# How to set Select keyword as default Item in Spinner

Tags: android

I have a problem that I have two spinners, second spinner is dependent on first (means when I select a item from 1st Spinner then according to that Second Spinner gets filled). But the problem is, I want Select Keyword as a default Item for both spinners, and when I will click on that, spinner should filled with parsed Info and when I will select an Item from first Spinner then the Parsing starts for Second Spinner but Spinner remains with default Select Keyword, when I will click on second spinner then it should be filled by the parsed Info.

How can I implement this, because when I am setting the adapter in any spinners its onItemSelectedListner first called, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can do this by Dialog, make a Customize dialog with List Box and fill the list with parsed data after click on TextBox which contains Select Keyword as a default.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **add "Select" as your first item** in your array list..
and on **click** event **of the Spinner** you just **remove the First item** from your array list

you will also find many similar question in Stack Overflow..search for it and you will get your exact answers with example.